# Problem solving and equations velocity distance time

Tags: proof-verification, problem-solving

It took 40 seconds for a train to completely pass a 2km tunnel. Find the velocity of the train. (The length of the train is 800m.)

What I have tried:

V=2800/40seconds
V= 700m/seconds

Comment: shouldn't it be $70$?

Comment: @Vasya You're right. I missed that. I'll delete my comment since it's not correct.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're looking to check your solution.

As you said, the velocity is equal to $$\frac{2800 \text{m}}{40 \text{s}}$$ but you have an extra zero. The answer should be:

$$\frac{2800 \text{m}}{40 \text{s}} = \frac{280 \text{m}}{4 \text{s}} = 7\color{red}{0} \text{m}/\text{s}$$

$700 \text{m}/\text{s}$ is the same magnitude as $700 \text{km}/\text{h}$ which is extremely fast for a train. Therefore your original answer must have ben off.